# Spring MVC with Thymeleaf. Update static data

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm using Spring MVC with Thymeleaf and Tomcat and I want to be able update static data (html pages) without redeploy.
In my application html is mapping by Spring controller.
Even JRebel doesn't helps. It updates java classes great, but does nothing with view.
What should I do to solve this issue? Maybe for html I need some listener mechanism like Jasper for JSP, or maybe I should disable some cache for Spring controller?..

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This actually was Thymeleaf issue.
I just had to disable caching for templateResolver, which is ON by default.

```
<bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/" /> 
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" /> 
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" /> 
    <property name="cacheable" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: I've been looking for that clue. Thank you, Maksim! Very helpful.

Comment: I have this setting set, but my pages still are cached, even when I restart the server.

Comment: Any idea why that might be?

Comment: If server restart doesn't help when it's not a Thymeleaf issue. It may be a browser's cache. Try to reload page using `Ctrl+F5`. If it helps, then one of this solutions may be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2068407/1430055 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/1341133/1430055

Comment: Thanks, the page not reloading was driving me crazy.

Comment: I tried to use <property name="cacheable" value="false"/> but it didn't work

Comment: in java config: `yourTemplateResolver.setCacheable(false);`