# tomcat7-maven-plugin - jsp/html no deployed

Tags: jsp, maven, hotdeploy, embedded-tomcat-7

Using the tomcat plugin "tomcat7-maven-plugin", I'm trying to get the "hot deploy" working with the embedded tomcat (using tomcat7:run).

I'm using a typical maven web app configuration under eclipse.
From now, I can debug my java class and they are getting redeployed automatically on a code change

But my html and jsp don't get **re**deployed (${basedir}/src/main/webapp).

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <update>true</update>
                <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

(I'm using the archetype "Thymeleaf Spring Maven Archetype").

Any idea how to get html and jsp redeployed on change ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe problem might be in the spring/thymeleaf config. Please make sure to disable thymeleaf templates caching in your spring configuration. See: [Spring MVC with Thymeleaf. Update static data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659142/spring-mvc-with-thymeleaf-update-static-data) ( specifically the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14659583/1581069)

In general, caching should be enabled for production only (sure, there might be exceptions, but...). On the other hand, in development people are interested in seeing the latest template updates in action.

**UPDATE**: After reading your question once again I'm getting confused, as you mentioned thymeleaf, but jsp as well. As far as I remember thymeleaf was doing html (as a jsp alternative). So is it thymeleaf you use, or jsp? Because I went for thymeleaf way only.

Comment: Great! Thymeleaf has cache enabled by default. It works many thanks !