# Intellij is not updating html file when updating resources

Tags: java, thymeleaf

Every time i change something on html file i have to restart the whole project. i tried:-

-> Edit Configurations -> server and changed on frame detection to update resources.

[image]

on my server tab update resources on frame detection is also on. but still i cannot update my html files and i have to restart server to reflect my changes.

[image]

Intellij Idea version is 2017.

Comment: But are you using plain html or a template engine that outputs html?

Comment: i use thymeleaf.

Comment: Ok. Are you using Spring framework by the way?

Comment: yes. yes. spring mvc and thymleaf as templating engine.

Answer (score 6):

You have to add this option in your properties file:

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

[Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-hotswapping.html#howto-reload-thymeleaf-content) is the documentation that explains this feature.

Comment: where do i pu this spring.thymeleaf.cache=false ?  i put it inside resources > application.properties. but it is not working?

Comment: Try to clear your browser's cache as @ochi said. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659142/spring-mvc-with-thymeleaf-update-static-data) is a post that could help you too.

Answer (score 1):

As @Juan Carlos Mendoza says you have to add this property

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

Plus to update the resources, hit Ctrl+F9 then the project will build the new resources and make them available

Comment: @sagar limbu, try hitting ctrl+F9 with every new change on templates folder